# could not install pci config handler for root bridge pci0

Tags: 18.04, thinkpad, pci

Before booting up Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on my Thinkpad T480s, this message appears with "`could not install pci config handler for root bridge pci0`" among the text.

I tried googling, but I wasn't abble to find much useful help.

Any ideas what the problem is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out my SSD is broken, so probably nothing to do with Ubuntu. Lenovo will send me a new one under warranty.

Answer (score 0):

I gave my laptop a few light kicks and it worked
*Not advised: I just did it to finish my last few days at work and then will throw it away